# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error

Tags: java, arrays, loops, error-handling

This runs smoothly from start to the first looping part, but when displaying the user input(on the second loop), the program stops and there is a message in the cmd:

```
(Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5 at 
CaseStudy2A.main(CaseStudy2A.java:17)
```

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CaseStudy2A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inp = new Scanner (System.in);
        int inpNum;
        System.out.print("Enter Number: ");
        inpNum = inp.nextInt();

        int num[]=new int [inpNum];

        int accu;

        for(int x=1;x<=inpNum;x++) {
            System.out.print("\nNumber [" + x + "] : ");
            accu = inp.nextInt();

            num[x]=accu;
        }
        for(int x=1;x<=inpNum;x++)
            System.out.println(num[x] + " ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array indexes starts from zero.

loop should be

```
   for(int x=1;x<inpNum;x++) {
```

For example

consider `inpNum= 5`  then

```
 int num[]=new int [5]; //5 elements ,position 0,1,2,3,4
```

`num[5]`  throws exception, since array initialized with 5 elements  `num[0]`  to  `num[4]`

And also in remaining places, change the condition to `x<inpNum` from `x<=inpNum`

Answer (score 0):

should be `for(int x=0;x<inpNum;x++) {`